# Recovery from Bad Library, Angular5 app fails compile related to CSS imports

Tags: javascript, angular

Working on an app with the current angular. Had imported a library for a component, but it ended up causing more issues than help, but I'm still having compilation errors, and I don't want to re-work this solution.

Here is the Error text:

> ERROR in
>   ./node_modules/css-loader?{"sourceMap":false,"importLoaders":1}!./node_modules/postcss-loader?{"ident":"postcss
>   "}!./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css Module build
>   failed: BrowserslistError: Unknown browser major
>       at error (C:\Users\rutherfordc.AA\Documents\GitHub\ccsng\node_modules\browserslist\index.js:37:11)
>       at Function.browserslist.checkName (C:\Users\rutherfordc.AA\Documents\GitHub\ccsng\node_modules\browserslist\index.j
>   s:320:18)
>       at Function.select (C:\Users\rutherfordc.AA\Documents\GitHub\ccsng\node_modules\browserslist\index.js:438:37)
>       at C:\Users\rutherfordc.AA\Documents\GitHub\ccsng\node_modules\browserslist\index.js:207:41
>       at Array.forEach ()
>       at browserslist (C:\Users\rutherfordc.AA\Documents\GitHub\ccsng\node_modules\browserslist\index.js:196:13)
>       at Browsers.parse (C:\Users\rutherfordc.AA\Documents\GitHub\ccsng\node_modules\autoprefixer\lib\browsers.js:44:14)
>       at new Browsers (C:\Users\rutherfordc.AA\Documents\GitHub\ccsng\node_modules\autoprefixer\lib\browsers.js:39:28)
>       at loadPrefixes (C:\Users\rutherfordc.AA\Documents\GitHub\ccsng\node_modules\autoprefixer\lib\autoprefixer.js:56:18)
>       at plugin (C:\Users\rutherfordc.AA\Documents\GitHub\ccsng\node_modules\autoprefixer\lib\autoprefixer.js:62:18)
>       at LazyResult.run (C:\Users\rutherfordc.AA\Documents\GitHub\ccsng\node_modules\postcss\lib\lazy-result.js:274:20)
>       at LazyResult.asyncTick (C:\Users\rutherfordc.AA\Documents\GitHub\ccsng\node_modules\postcss\lib\lazy-result.js:189:
>   32)
>       at LazyResult.asyncTick (C:\Users\rutherfordc.AA\Documents\GitHub\ccsng\node_modules\postcss\lib\lazy-result.js:201:
>   22)
>       at processing.Promise.then._this2.processed (C:\Users\rutherfordc.AA\Documents\GitHub\ccsng\node_modules\postcss\lib
>   \lazy-result.js:228:20)
>       at Promise ()
>       at LazyResult.async (C:\Users\rutherfordc.AA\Documents\GitHub\ccsng\node_modules\postcss\lib\lazy-result.js:225:27)
>   @
>   ./node_modules/css-loader?{"sourceMap":false,"importLoaders":1}!./node_modules/postcss-loader?{"ident":"postcss"}!./n
>   ode_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js?{"sourceMap":false,"precision":8,"includePaths":[]}!./src/styles.sass
>   5:10-202  @ ./src/styles.sass  @ multi ./src/styles.sass

According to the first few lines in the error, it's related to Bootstrap in Node_modules, but I'm importing it in my style.sass file (which compiles down to CSS) as

```
@import url("../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css")
```

No Idea why it's failing now.

Answer (score 0):

Removed all imports from Styles.sass and the angular-cli.json files and add the imports to the Index.html file. (Despite it working prior.)